# MYSQL query: Remove duplicates from query while adding counts

Tags: mysql

Hello SQL ninja's I could use some advice on a query I'm working on.

I have a table full of Call Detail Records.  I want to search for the total number of calls made by a device.  The device can either be the originator of a call or the destination of a call.  There are 2 columns to represent this, `origDeviceName` and `destDeviceName`.

Searching though Stackoverflow I was able to come up with a query to get most of what I want.

The problem is because i'm using a `UNION` and a device can be both an originator or a destination my results contain duplicates.  For example

```
 devices  |  count
 __________________
 PRI      | 32
 SIP      | 17
 PRI      | 24
 SIP      | 10
```

The desired result is a list of devices without duplicates and total count for each device.  For example:

```
  devices  |  count
 __________________
 PRI      | 56
 SIP      | 27
```

This is the query i'm using: (note im just using the `NOT LIKE` and `<>` to filter out devices of a certain type)

```
 SELECT devices, count
   FROM (SELECT origDeviceName as devices
                , COUNT(origDeviceName) AS count
           FROM CDR 
          WHERE origDeviceName NOT LIKE 'SEP%' 
            AND origDeviceName NOT LIKE'CSF%' 
            AND origDeviceName <> ' ' GROUP BY devices
          UNION
         SELECT destDeviceName as devices
                , COUNT(destDeviceName) AS count
           FROM CDR WHERE destDeviceName NOT LIKE 'SEP%' 
            AND destDeviceName NOT LIKE 'CSF%' 
            AND destDeviceName <> ' ' 
          GROUP BY devices) 
    AS All_Devices
```

I've tried using `GROUP BY` at the end also which will filter out the duplicates but I cant figure out how to combine the counts for each device.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should use `union all` rather than `union`.  Second, you want an aggregation at the outer level:

```
SELECT d.devices, sum(count)
FROM ((SELECT origDeviceName as devices, COUNT(origDeviceName) AS count
       FROM CDR
       WHERE origDeviceName NOT LIKE 'SEP%' AND
             origDeviceName NOT LIKE'CSF%' AND
             origDeviceName <> ' '
       GROUP BY devices
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT  destDeviceName as devices, COUNT(destDeviceName) AS count
       FROM CDR
       WHERE destDeviceName NOT LIKE 'SEP%' AND
             destDeviceName NOT LIKE 'CSF%' AND
             destDeviceName <> ' '
       GROUP BY devices
      )
     ) d
GROUP BY d.devices;
```